# How to define a map of mappings?

Tags: isabelle

There are 2 kinds of values in the theory - `val1` and `val2`:

```
type_synonym bool3 = "bool option"

datatype val1 = BVal1 bool3 | IVal1 int | SVal1 string
datatype val2 = BVal2 bool | IVal2 int
```

I can map them using either the following inductive predicate:

```
inductive map_val_ind :: "val1 ⇒ val2 ⇒ bool" where
  "map_val_ind (BVal1 (Some v)) (BVal2 v)"
| "map_val_ind (IVal1 v) (IVal2 v)"

code_pred [show_modes] map_val_ind .

values "{t. map_val_ind (BVal1 (Some True)) t}"
```

or the following function:

```
fun map_val :: "val1 ⇒ val2 option" where
  "map_val (BVal1 (Some v)) = Some (BVal2 v)"
| "map_val (IVal1 v) = Some (IVal2 v)"
| "map_val _ = None"

value "map_val (BVal1 (Some True))"
```

I prefer inductive predicate, because it's bidirectional.

Also I need to map environments of variables:

```
type_synonym vname = "string"
type_synonym 'a env = "vname ⇒ 'a option"
```

1) Here is a first attempt to define the mapping:

```
definition map_env :: "val1 env ⇒ val2 env ⇒ bool" where
  "map_env env1 env2 ≡ ∀x. ∃y z.
    env1 x = Some y ∧
    env2 x = Some z ∧
    map_val_ind y z"
```

The problem is that it's not constructive, and I don't understand how to map an environment using this definition.

2) Here is a functional definition:

```
definition map_env_fun :: "val1 env ⇒ (val2 env) option" where
  "map_env_fun env = (if ∀x. ∃y z. env x = Some y ∧ map_val y = Some z
    then Some (λx. map_val (the (env x)))
    else None)"

value "map_env_fun [''x'' ↦ BVal1 (Some True)]"
```

But I get the following error:

```
Wellsortedness error
(in code equation map_env_fun ?env ≡
                  if ∀x. ∃y z. equal_option_inst.equal_option (?env x) (Some y) ∧
                               equal_option_inst.equal_option (map_val y) (Some z)
                  then Some (λx. map_val (the (?env x))) else None,
with dependency "Pure.dummy_pattern" -> "map_env_fun"):
Type char list not of sort enum
No type arity list :: enum
```

3) And here is an inductive version:

```
inductive map_env_ind :: "val1 env ⇒ val2 env ⇒ bool" where
  "env1 x = Some y ⟹
   env2 x = Some z ⟹
   map_val_ind y z ⟹
   map_env_ind env1 env2"

code_pred [show_modes] map_env_ind .
```

The problem is that `code_pred` can't infer any execution modes.

How to define such an environment mapping? I prefer an inductive version, because it's bidirectional and it's easier to prove lemmas for inductive predicates.